# Audio Drivers for Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7

I have an Acer Aspire 3910 desktop but i have failed to get the audio drivers for Windows 7 Enterprise edition. Can anyone help me with a source for the drivers?

Comment: You can use the same drivers as any other edition of Windows 7, so long as it's the right bit-level (32-bit or 64-bit). Failing that, try the Windows Vista drivers.

Answer (score 1):

According to Acer's [website](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?modelId=2217), there are drivers for Windows 7 Ultimate, which is the equivalent of Windows 7 Enterprise.

For completeness, here is my original comment for your question:

You can use the same drivers as any other edition of Windows 7, so long as it's the right bit-level (32-bit or 64-bit). Failing that, try the Windows Vista drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for drivers for Windows Vista if you can't find drivers for Windows 7.  And Enterprise vs Home Premium vs Professional does not matter for Windows drivers, ever.  What does matter is 32bit (x86) vs 64bit (x64).  As a last ditch effort you can also look for drivers for the equivalent server operating system (xp=2003, vista=2008, 7=2008 R2), but if the other options failed this doesn't have very good odds for success.

Answer (score 0):

Some Windows Vista drivers can be installed in Windows 7 in "Windows Vista compatibility mode" even it can not be installed directly

Answer (score 0):

You can get the drivers straight from Realtek: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false